Error Generating New CLI with oclif: Issues with Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type
I'm working on creating a new CLI tool using the oclif framework and TypeScript, but I’m running into issues when trying to build the project
After generating cli it errors out
Then trying to manually npm run build(shx rm -rf dist && tsc -b) it also error out
tsconfig is the default

What could be causing these TypeScript errors with @types/jest, and how can I resolve them to successfully build my oclif CLI project?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Could you add the content of your tsconfig.json?

Nevermind solve it, by adding "skipLibCheck": true in my tsconfig.json
Also Adding mocha chai node as types in tsconfig.json fixes the error

Dont know why this 3 errored out to begin with


Please do not upload images of text.
